# How to go from array to list and back again using PIL?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to put my image in list form in order to insert pixels to the image. However, I'm running into issues on converting back to an image once I've done the list manipulation. Turns out just going from image -> array -> list -> array -> image messes up the image pretty good.

However, going from image -> array -> image seems to work just fine. It's that extra step of going to a list that's causing issues.

Below is the python3 code I'm running. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to get the 3D list converted back into an RGB image that is identical to the original? Both the original and final arrays appear to be the same so not sure what PIL doesn't like...

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image              

img = Image.open('1.jpg') 
array = np.array(img)              

list1 = array.tolist()             
arrayF = np.array(list1)                                                

img2 = Image.fromarray(arrayF,"RGB")
img2.save('trial.jpg')

print(array)
print(arrayF)
```

Comment: Try printing the `dtype` of your Numpy arrays, e.g. `print(arrayF.dtype)`

Comment: PIL is a Python 2 only library that has not been updated for a decade.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you, that's likely it. array.dtype = uint8 & arrayF.dtype = int64. I'll look up how to convert.

Comment: `Eightbitarray = sixtyfourbitarray.astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell That worked. Thank you! post as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the `dtype` of your arrays, with `print(array.dtype)`, you will see that `array` is 8-bit and `arrayF` is 64-bit... which is [unacceptable](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) to PIL for an RGB image.

Make `arrayF` back into 8-bit with:

```
arrayF = arrayF.astype(np.uint8)
```